# Replace string in one file with contents of another file when match column

Tags: text-processing, replace

I have two files like:

file 1 :

```
a stringori to replace, this stringori comme again 
other stringori2 to replace, stringori2 commes again
...
```

file 2:

```
stringori newstring
stringori2  newstring2
...
```

I want to get the result:

```
a newstring to replace, this newstring comme again 
other newstring2 to replace, newstring2 commes again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has been solved / answered umpteen times in these fora. How about

```
awk 'NR == FNR {T[$1] = $2; next} {for (t in T) gsub (t, T[t])} 1' file2 file1
    a newstring to replace, this newstring comme again 
    other newstring2 to replace, newstring2 commes again
```